# Observer isn't powering the door

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am trying to make a piston door that will activate when I open a barrel, but the observer isn't powering the door. If use something else to activate it, it works.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your picture shows very little about how you wired everything up. I assume your redstone doesn't connect to the torch correctly. You can wire it by using a repeater going into the redstone torch.

[image: view of what i did]